# mencoder FAAC support on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mencoder, libfaac

I am trying to get FAAC support in mencoder on Ubuntu 14.04 (server).  These are the steps I took.

```
apt-get install libfaac-dev libfaad-dev faac faad
apt-get install mplayer mencoder
```

After that I run:

```
ldd /usr/bin/mencoder | grep faac
```

No results.  Even this command verifies no FAAC support.

```
mencoder -oac help
MEncoder 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team

Available codecs:
    copy
    pcm
    mp3lame
    lavc
```

I saw some people say there was a licensing issue but that seemed to be older versions of Ubuntu.  That could still be true in 14.04 and if so what are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the ideal answer but hopefully it will help someone else out in the future.  The short and long answer is, if you want FAAC support in mencoder on Ubuntu then you need to build it from source.  I did just that and all works well.